# Why don't I get warned about Scanner 'Resource Leak' when declared in Class?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, java.util.scanner

When I write a code like this :

```
void methodName(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int inp = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(inp);
}
```

I get a 'Resource leak' warning, which suggests I should close the `Scanner` instance. But when I define `sc` outside the method, like this :

```
class MyClass{
    Scanner sc;

    void methodName(){
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int inp = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(inp);
    }
}
```

I don't get a 'Resource leak' warning, Why so ?

Another small question, If I do `sc = null;`, I suppose the `Scanner` object will be eligible for Garbage Collection since it's not referenced anymore, thus freeing memory, right ? So is `sc = null;` enough to solve the 'Resource leak' without `sc.close();` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first instance, `sc` falls out of scope at the end of the method.  The expectation is therefore that it will be closed*.

In the second instance, because `sc` is a class-level field, it will remain in scope at the end of the method.  The expectation is therefore that it will be used in other methods, and will be closed at a more appropriate time.

*Closing `Scanner`s reading from `System.in` is not recommended as it inhibits further keyboard input.

EDIT (having just seen your follow-up question): The garbage collector only frees up memory.  It does not also clean up other resources the object is holding (file handles, network connections, locks, etc).